# How to compare entity identity in Core Data

Tags: core-data

What is the preferred way to compare two Core Data entities for identity in the same context?

Is it OK to just use object identity and do `EntityOne == EntityTwo` as long as I'm sure they're both in the same context? That is, am I guaranteed that for each Core Data entity, a maximum of one Cocoa Object representation exists per ManagedObjectContext?

If not, what is the preferred way? In my model, every Core Data Entity has a UUID property anyway, I'm sure that one is safe (but also slower) to compare. What's the best practice here (and for posterity, what if one's model doesn't have the UUID?)

How about comparisons across contexts? `[EntityOne inContext:moc] == [entityTwo inContext:moc]` or similar, or is there a faster/better/more elegant way?

Comment: Do you mean entity as in an instance of `NSEntityDescription`?

Comment: No, I meant two Core Data "objects". Two rows in the same table in the database (assuming an SQLite store). Or, as the case may be, the same row. That's what I want to test for. I think Tom has already answered the question, but if you have anything to add, I'd be glad to read it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know whether two managed objects represent the same underlying instance, the correct approach is to compare their `objectID` properties using `isEqual:`.

If the two objects were fetched from the same context, they're *actually the same object*, because Core Data doesn't create multiple objects for the same instance in the same context. Using `==` should be fine in that strictly limited case. Using `==` in any other situation will give incorrect results.